# SQL Server stored procedure causes Visual Studio to hang when added as part of a dataset

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, while-loop, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I've got a T-SQL stored procedure, which for a given set of parameters returns 34 rows and takes less then a fraction of a second to run.

The SQL has a while loop, a bunch of nested if statements a handful of modes. It used to have a few `goto:` statements, but I changed them to `If` statements.

All appropriate access (select to  tables, exec to procedures) has been granted.

Whenever I try to add the SQL as a stored procedure to SSRS to build a report to pull the contents that are returned from the procedure the SSRS hangs. Just hangs. Wheel is spinning and it seems to be taking for ever.

I did run a test, and I am able to connect to the server, I was able to add a different procedure without issue in seconds. But something about this one keeps making it crash.

First a few labels are declared, mostly dates.

Then a few local tables are created.

Then we have a while loop that reads
while 1=1, and I wonder if that could be causing some kind of infinite loop in SSRS.

Then syntax reads if a date value > another date value
break (out of the loop)

else
insert and update a bunch of stuff into the temp tables.

It does have syntax that starts

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
Parameters 
    @season_str varchar(255),
    @event_start_dt datetime,
    @event_end_dt datetime,
    @sale_end_dt datetime) 

------------------

declare @sale_start_dt datetime
select @sale_start_dt = dateadd(dd,-6,@sale_end_dt)

declare @run_date datetime,
    @include_donated char(1)

--need to report on sales the day before the start date of the report so that we
-- can know how many were sold on day 1 of the report.
select @run_date = dateadd(dd,-1,@sale_start_dt)
select @include_donated = 'N'

create table #t1 (
    perf_no int NOT NULL,
    ...
    )

while 1=1
begin
select @run_date = dateadd(dd,1,@run_date)

if convert(datetime,convert(varchar,@run_date,101)) > convert(datetime,convert(varchar,@sale_end_dt,101))
    BREAK

else 
    begin

    if convert(varchar,@run_date,101) = convert(varchar,getdate(),101)
    --if the run_date is today then we want to get up-to-date numbers so we run the procc with @run_date = NULL
    begin --run_date = NULL

       insert into #t1 ( field names )
       exec LP_SALES_SUMMARY_PTC @event_start_dt, @event_end_dt, @season_str,   NULL, @include_donated
       update #t1 set run_date = @run_date, step = 1 where run_date is null

    end --run_date is not null

    else
    begin --run_date is not NULL
    --if the run date is in the past, run the procedure with @run_date <> NULL
        insert into #t1 ( field names )
        exec LP_SALES_SUMMARY_PTC @event_start_dt, @event_end_dt, @season_str,  NULL, @include_donated
         update #t1 set run_date = @run_date, step = 1 where run_date is null


    if (select count(*) from #t1 where run_date = @run_date) = 0
    begin
        if getdate() >='08/29/2007' -- start of historic information
        begin

        insert into #t1 ( field names )
        exec LP_SALES_SUMMARY_PTC @event_start_dt, @event_end_dt, @season_str,  NULL, @include_donated
        update #t1 set run_date = @run_date, step = 1 where run_date is null
    end

    else
    begin
      
       insert into #t1 ( field names )
       exec RP_SALES_SUMMARY_PTC @event_start_dt, @event_end_dt, @season_str,   NULL, @include_donated
      update #t1 set run_date = @run_date, step = 1 where run_date is null
    end
    end
    end

end
    
-- more code continuation
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand there are hundreds of lines of code, and i'm certain the cause of the issue isn't anything related to basic selects/updates.

Comment: Well, one potential problem that could cause a loop to go infinite is if your date logic relies on strings in some ambiguous/regional format, that you may have different languages in play and dates are interpreted differently. We don't need to see hundreds of lines of code, but the basic structure of the loop (and how you break out of it), as well as any parameters, their types, values, and how they're passed in, would be a lot more useful than "it can't possibly be the code, but here's a vague description of what the code does."

Comment: @AaronBertrand code added

Comment: I updated the clean up with the dates, and added the rest of the if/else combos the insert statements just have a bunch of fields that come from another procedure that calculate total counts and dollar amounts

Comment: The insert / exec commands all look identical regardless of which conditions are hit. Is this intentional, or was this just copy / paste and the actual commands are different? I think this is just copy / paste because I assume the 4th parameter to the stored procedure is the run date?

Comment: I did miss an if/else statement after the first if - apologies, and the end I did copy, but its RP vs LP (there was an original procedure RP and then it was localized to be LP) I've generally not worked with these before I just have to make it come through in SSRS and make a presentable report. its somewhat strange to me

Comment: Debugging tip: If you have a loop with a possibility of it running away, add a little code to perform a reality check. Keep a count of iterations and [`throw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) an exception if it gets out-of-hand. (Yes, the message should include the count.) You can set the limit at `1` (or `0`) just to confirm that the code is executing. The code can remain in production if there is a suitable limit, e.g. `100000` days would cover about 273 years of data.

Comment: @HABO yes! Always a good idea. I suggest something similar in [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6966/sql-while-loop-avoid-while-1-equals-1/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) (see `@ExpectedIterations`).

Comment: My advice is to add print statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what's different about the calls to the stored procedure, but instead of the `WHILE 1=1` pattern ([which is *notorious* for causing infinite loops](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6966/sql-while-loop-avoid-while-1-equals-1/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)), I'd much rather make the condition based on the values. Also instead of subtracting a day from the start and then adding a day immediately inside the loop, it is simpler to leave the start day as is, and not increment it until the *end* of the loop.

I left out the creation and update of `#t1`, but here is how I would re-structure your variables and loop:

```
/* params */
DECLARE @season_str     varchar(255),
        @event_start_dt date,
        @event_end_dt   date,
        @sale_end_dt    date;

/* local variables */
declare @sale_start_dt   date    = dateadd(DAY, -6, @sale_end_dt);
declare @run_date        date    = @sale_start_dt,
        @today           date    = getdate(),
        @beginningOfTime date    = '20070829', -- start of historic info
        @include_donated char(1) = 'N';
...

WHILE @run_date <= @sale_end_dt
BEGIN
  if @run_date = @today 
  begin
    --insert into #t1 (...) EXEC LP_SALES_SUMMARY_PTC with null run_date
  end
  else
  begin
    --insert into #t1 (...) EXEC LP_SALES_SUMMARY_PTC with non-null run_date
  end

  if NOT EXISTS (select 1 from #t1 where run_date = @run_date)
  begin
    if @today >= @beginningOfTime -- start of historic information
    begin
      --insert into #t1 (...) EXEC LP_SALES_SUMMARY_PTC ... -- should it be RP?
    end
    else
    begin -- how could this ever be reached?
      --insert into #t1 (...) EXEC RP_SALES_SUMMARY_PTC ...;
    end
  end
  set @run_date = dateadd(DAY, 1, @run_date);
END
```

Comment: code changes worked, the visual studio definitely is happier without the infinite loop. Thank you for your patience. I also don't know if that second to last LP should be an RP - I'll do some research into this further, I really appreciate the help.